# Are the answers solved to these questions correct or wrong?

Tags: functions

Functions f and g are given as f(x) = x^2 - x and g(x) = 2x - 3,
(a) Find f(0), f(-1), g(0) and g(-1).

(b) If f(x) + g(x) = 3, find x.

(c) If f(p) + g(-p) = 1 , find p.

(d) If f(z) = g(z) + 1, Find z

I found my answers as follows:-

(a) f(0) = 0, f(-1) = 0, g(0) = -3, g(-1) = -5

(b) x = 2 or x = -3

(c) p = -1 or p = 4

(d) z = 1 or z = 2

Correct me if am wrong!
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could show your work for each part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have got $$f(0)=0,f(-1)=2,g(0)=-3,g(-1)=-5$$
$$x=-3,x=2$$
$$p=-1,p=4$$
$$z=2$$
$$z=1$$
we have to solve $$z^2-z=2z-3+1$$ and this is $$z^2-3z+2=0$$
$$z_{1,2}=\frac{3}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-\frac{8}{4}}$$

Comment: Can you show me how you solved for z.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I managed to find a mistake at point *(a)*:
$$ f(-1) = (-1)^2 - (-1)$$
$$f(-1) = 1 + 1\implies f(-1) = 2$$

Comment: Oh right, how could i have missed that. Thanks.